# How to make a composite SQL statement

Tags: sql, birt

I have a problem with a query, 
I need to make a composite SQL Statement
Ex. I know the Student ID and his grades is saved in table in rows " Subject ID, Subject Name, Student ID, Grade", I need to retrieve all his grades from grades table 
but as columns not rows.

so the report would be like the below:-

Student ID,Physics,Mathematics,Chemistry

User will enter the student id and i have to retrieve student grades like the previous line.
Could you please help me in this issue

Thanks in Advance,

Comment: Can you edit the question to show where you want the grades to be displayed?  And clarify if the report would show only single student at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in addition to Mark's answer
i have solved it using SQL Crosstab queries

https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/creating-cross-tab-queries-and-pivot-tables-in-sql/

Comment: Note that even according to the linked article, doing this in SQL should be the exception, not the rule: *"There is a general rule which states that data manipulation of this sort is best left to the application or reporting levels of the system, and for good reason... I leave you with the advice that the script described here should be used carefully and sparingly, and not sprinkled willy-nilly about your databases."*

Answer (score 1):

This would be better achieved in BIRT rather than in the query, by using a crosstab - see [here](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.birt.doc/birt/crosstab.17.1.html) for details on how.

Comment: Thank you Mark for your Reply and your answer